# Meaning of the phrase "test case" in context

Tags: meaning

I know the phrase means in general, but I am confused by it in the following sentence.

> "North Korea is the only country that  sticks with strict communism, but they are too isolated to be **a test case** for an economic system.

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly about this sentence confuses you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [*test case*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/test-case):

> a case that, after its determination, is likely to be used as a precedent.

In your example, meaning even if their economic system were successful, it probably could not be duplicated elsewhere because their isolationist policies don't exist elsewhere.